# Codeblock returns bad output in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, output

I have a problem with my code block software in mac. Whenever I hit build or run button the code that is compiled is not returned correctly in the terminal. For example, I try to compile a simple code as in the picture and the result which is highlighted in green is wrong. I can't seem to find if it is code block or terminal faults. Would be glad if anyone can help.

Code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any values for a and b,

What you print is their memory address (`&a` and `&b`), not their values.

In my screenshot, everything looks normal.

By the way, I'm curious how comes are you using "CodeBlocks"? (Recommendation from a friend?)
It looks very old, and there are [better environments](https://www.slant.co/topics/5988/~ides-for-c-on-mac-os-x) to program in c/c++ on a Mac.

[image]

Comment: ohh , i see and you are right that i haven't declared values for a and b.I found almost the same error in some of my other exercises and a few other similar ones.Thank you very much.                                                                                                                      The reason i use codeblocks is because it is used in my c class and my teachers still keep using it.So i use it so i can be in a line with my classmates whenever i have a problem with my code.I don't like it either.What environment would you recommend from that list?

Comment: Yes I understand you are using the same editor with your teacher and classmates. I don't have any recommendation. In your case it should just be fine to use CodeBlocks. I like to use only the Terminal, very lightweight, or Xcode as it gives a lot of information. You may try any other just for fun.

Comment: Ok thank you then, i will try xcode then as i find it nice.Have a nice day.

Comment: Xcode is more modern and has lots of cool features. Enjoy your programming adventure;